# Why console.log so slow in Expo android but fast in Expo ios

Tags: react-native, expo, console.log

I have an issue about console.log on my expo project.
On my windows it takes about a minute to start showing the log but it shows instantly on my MacOS
My Windows specs:
Windows 10
Storage: SSD 
Ram: 8GB

Comment: try restarting the server, if it's running for a long time and also had hopped between different networks.

Comment: create new project, with minimal content, and test the console.log

Comment: Which emulator do you use?

Comment: @izniburak emulator Android Studio Nexus 9

Comment: Android Emulators usually work slowly. I don't know why reason of this. You can try to use Genymotion as emulator. I think Genymotion has better performance rather than Android Emulators. BTW, You can install Intel/Haxm to improve emulator performance. You can check this ref: https://github.com/intel/haxm/wiki/Installation-Instructions-on-macOS @NGUYEN HUU PHUC HPIT